# Is Spring Data Mongodb, how can I reference one document from another without going via IDs

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using MongoDB with Spring Data. I'd like to have one document reference another (a user in fact), but I end up with having to do extra work. E.g.

```
class Watch {
    String id;
    User user;
}
```

That's nice, but I seem to end up with the whole user embedded in the document, so I do this:

```
class Watch {
    String id;
    String userId;
}
```

But then I want to use it in some JSTL, and I want to do this:

```
${watch.user.email}
```

But I have to add some mapping code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use @DBRef annotation on user.

You need to save user separately (no cascading), but you probably want to do that.

Beware that user will be loaded eagerly.

Comment: I know that this is too late, but you actually CAN load it lazily as well, just use `@DbRef(lazy = true)`